# Функция, принимающая на вход массив и целое число. И возвращает индекс этого числа в массиве. Где ошибка?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

  public static int getPosition(int[] array, int x) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
        if (array[i] == x) return i;
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    return -1;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a = {3,10,-5,15,23,48,-30};
    int x = 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка там, где Вы *не вызываете* функцию `getPosition`.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {3, 10, -5, 15, 23, 48, -30};
    int x = 5;
    System.out.print(getPosition(a, x)); // -1
  }
```

А также там, где Вы зачем-то выводите `i` в цикле.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == x) return i;
    //System.out.print(i);
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!!!

Comment: @АндрейТюгаев Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.